# "Non-nullable instance field '_items' must be initialized.\nTry adding an initializer it

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a modal for shopping cart but this gives me an error.
my dart sdk version:2.12.0>3.0.0

I tried using 'late' before this map  but it giving me error in output result that lateinitialization error: field '_items' has not be initialized

```
 Map<String, CartItem> _items;




import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class CartItem with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final int quantity;
  final double price;

  CartItem(
      {required this.id,
      required this.title,
      required this.price,
      required this.quantity});
}

class Cart with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, CartItem> _items;       //error _items

  Map<String, CartItem> get items {
    return {..._items};
  }

  int get itemcount {
    return _items.length;
  }

  void addItems(String productId, double price, String title) {
    if (_items.containsKey(productId)) {
      _items.update(
        productId,
        (existing) => CartItem(
            id: existing.id,
            title: existing.title,
            price: existing.price,
            quantity: existing.quantity + 1),
      );
    } else {
      _items.putIfAbsent(
          productId,
          () => CartItem(
              id: DateTime.now().toString(),
              title: title,
              price: price,
              quantity: 1));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `_items` variable with `{}` empty map.

```dart
Map<String, CartItem> _items = {};
```